# Library not getting invoked

Tags: r

I am trying to use the library(numbers) in R-Script. But it is giving below error:

> library(numbers)
>   Error in library(numbers) : there is no package called 'numbers'

I have installed the package successfully:

```
> packageDescription('numbers')
Package: numbers
Type: Package
Title: Number-Theoretic Functions
Version: 0.7-1
Date: 2018-05-16
Author: Hans Werner Borchers
Maintainer: Hans W. Borchers <hwborchers@googlemail.com>
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)
Suggests: gmp (>= 0.5-1)
Description: Provides number-theoretic functions for factorization,
       prime numbers, twin primes, primitive roots, modular logarithm
       and inverses, extended GCD, Farey series and continuous
       fractions.  Includes Legendre and Jacobi symbols, some divisor
       functions, Euler's Phi function, etc.
License: GPL (>= 3)
Repository: CRAN
Repository/R-Forge/Project: optimist
Repository/R-Forge/Revision: 453
Repository/R-Forge/DateTimeStamp: 2018-05-16 18:50:43
Date/Publication: 2018-05-17 08:49:01 UTC
NeedsCompilation: no
Packaged: 2018-05-16 19:15:14 UTC; rforge
Built: R 3.4.4; ; 2019-09-19 20:28:04 UTC; unix
```

Can someone help me what to do now?
I want to use the LCM function in R script from library(numbers)

Comment: look at `.libPaths()` -- try `sapply(.libPaths(), list.files, pattern = 'numbers')` to see if the library is where R is looking for it

Comment: @MichaelChirico 
 got this:

$`C:/Users/anshul.s/Documents/R/win-library/3.6`
[1] "numbers"

$`C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library`
character(0)

Comment: It's a bit strange, it seems it should load. Can you restart R and/or your computer and try again? Maybe there's a DLL issue. You can also run `getNamespaceInfo('numbers', 'path')` to confirm it matches the path you found with `.libPaths()`

Comment: @MichaelChirico - Path is matching. Let me try restarting the PC
"C:/Users/anshul.s/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/numbers"

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
install.packages("numbers")
```

to install the library again and then try restarting your Rstudio, it might help

```
library(numbers)
```

i tried it out

by this u can make sure if its [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad0X8.jpg) installed properly